# Trying to add minimum and maximum outputs

Tags: java, max, min

I have read a few of the suggested answers they seem helpfuil but too complicated for me to confidently understand and add to my program.

Can anyone suggest ways to output the min and max from 1st and 2nd years sales figures?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class assignment2
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome!\n");
        System.out.println("Month 0 - January");
        System.out.println("Month 11 - December\n");
        System.out.println("MonthNo(year1)\tSales made\n");

        double sales[] = { 60, 54, 62, 67, 54, 67, 51, 50, 62, 55, 49, 70 };
        int sum = 0;
        int average12 = 0;

        for (int counter = 0; counter < sales.length; counter++)
        {
            sum += sales[counter];
            System.out.println(counter + "\t\t\t\t\t\t" + sales[counter]);
        }

        System.out.println("\nTotal year 1 sales " + sum + "\n");

 /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    System.out.println("MonthNo(year2)\tSales made\n");

    double sales2[] = { 59, 43, 48, 51, 49, 57, 39, 42, 54, 51, 60, 62 };
    int sum2 = 0;

for (int counter = 0; counter < sales2.length; counter++)
        {
        sum2 += sales2[counter];
        System.out.println(counter + "\t\t\t\t\t\t" + sales2[counter]);
    }

    System.out.println("\nTotal year 2 sales " + sum2 + "\n");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the maximum and minimum sales of your arrays, you can use `java.util.Arrays.sort` to sort the arrays and then the minimum sales would be the first element of the array and the maximum sales would be the last element of the array.

Example -

```
Arrays.sort(sales);
System.out.println("\nLowest Sales Year1 " + sales[0]);
System.out.println("\nHighest Sales Year1 " + sales[sales.length-1]);
Arrays.sort(sales2);
System.out.println("\nLowest Sales Year2 " + sales2[0]);
System.out.println("\nHighest Sales Year2 " + sales2[sales2.length-1]);
```

Comment: This does make sense, I am strictly only allowed to use the scanner utility unfortunately so could not use array sort utility. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

For getting the minimum value, just keep a `currentMin` and every time you iterate, you compare the current value in the loop `sales[counter]` vs the `currentMin`. From this, you should be able to get the `max`.

```
double currentMin = sales[0];
for (int counter = 0; counter < sales.length; counter++) {
   sum += sales[counter];
   System.out.println(counter + "\t\t\t\t\t\t" + sales[counter]);

   //compare
   if(sales[counter] < currentMin) {
      currentMin = sales[counter];
   }
}
System.out.println("Min is " + currentMin);
```